# Angular UI-Bootstrap - Collapse function not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have been following the [docs for ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). And in the section(ui.bootstrap.collapse) they talk about making a collapse function for content when you click a button.

But I cannot seem to make the Collapse seem to work in my code.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

I have looked at other Stacks and have seen that other people use anchor tags instead of button tags. So I don't think that is the issue.

**Index HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="stuff">
<meta name="keywords" content="stuff">
<meta name="author" content="stuff">

<title> Title</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

<!-- Custom styles -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/svg_style.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!--Jquery -->
<script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular -->
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="index_body">
<div data-ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
    <div class="top-header" data-ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
</div>

    <div class="page [[ pageClass ]]" ng-view autoscroll="true"></div>

<!-- Main JS -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/headerCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/modal.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ResonanceCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ContactCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/LandingCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/SignInCtrl.js"></script>

<!-- Directives -->
<!-- <script src="js/directives/LandingAnimation.js"></script> -->


<script src="js/jq.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Landing Page HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5">
    <div class="caption">
         <h1 class="text-left h-color thin">
  Text Header
</h1>

        <p class="lead p-color">More Text</p>
        <!-- Here is my Toggle Button --> <a class="lead p-color learn-button togglebtn shake shake-rotate" data-ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"> 
  <small>
  <i class="glyphicon" data-ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': status.open, 'glyphicon-plus': !status.open}"></i> Learn More
  </small>
</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-7 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-6">
    <img alt="Image" class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/kip-animation.png" />
</div>

<!--Here is the what I want to collapse -->
<div id="myContent" collapse="isCollapsed" class="row row-offset row-pad" style="margin: 0 30px">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="lead caption text-center">
             <h3 class="h-color2">Item 1</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img style="height: 100px; width: auto;" class="img-circle" src="images/logo-bunny.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
        <div class="lead caption">
            <p class="p-color"><small>Text</small>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="lead caption text-center">
             <h3 class="h-color2">Item 2</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img style="height: 100px; width: auto;" class="img-circle" src="images/logo-bunny.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="lead caption">
            <p class="p-color"><small>Text</small>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="lead caption text-center">
             <h3 class="h-color2">Item 3</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img style="height: 100px; width: auto;" class="img-circle" src="images/logo-bunny.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="lead caption">
            <p class="p-color"> <small>Some Text</small>

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END DROPDOWN-->
```

**App Javascript**

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');

  $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
      templateUrl : 'pages/LandingPage.html',
      controller : 'LandingCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/signin'});
});
```

**Controller Javascript**

```
app.controller('LandingCtrl', function($scope) { // jshint ignore:line
$scope.pageClass = 'page-landing';

$scope.isCollapsed = true;

});
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work :( It's not even bootstrapping the angular app (e.g. where is the `ng-app="app"` in your HTML? Same could be said of the code you've posted here.

Comment: @SunilD. I updated my Stack. For some reason it works in the JsFiddle if I put the script into the actual html. It is still not working in my app. So I put up more of how it is working in my project to give you a better understanding.

Comment: Ok, this is starting to make more sense now. One thing I'm seeing that may be problematic is in LandingPage.html (based on your fiddle), you do `ng-controller="LandingCtrl"`. But since you are using `ngRoute` and have already specified which controller to use in the route definition, you are instantiating two controllers. It could be as simple as that, but who knows. I usually specify the controllers in the route definitions, and leave it out of the HTML.

Comment: @SunilD. No, I actually don't have the ng-controller defined in the actual html. I just had it in the fiddle because it needs it to work in fiddle. I put the actual code for that page's html in there now and deleted the fiddle. I have defined the controller only once in the app. So that is not the problem.

Comment: This kind of sounds like a directive (ng-if, ng-include, etc.) is creating another scope, thus shadowing the `isCollapsed` property in the controller. But I don't see any thing in your HTML that would do that. To trouble shoot, I try inserting statements in the HTML to see what the values are: `is collapsed: {{isCollapsed}}` ... Do this just above the click handler and just above (or inside) the container that is to be collapsed. Are the values "true" at the beginning? Do either values change when you trigger the click handler? Might shed some light...

Comment: Just fyi you don't use  ui-bootstrap.js and ui-bootstrap-tpls.js together.  One file contains the templates and directives while the other is just the directives.  So make sure to use either or not both.

Comment: Seems to be working fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/bdF4XnCiVhnnmM00QpEk?p=info.  Check the console for errors.  If something else in your app is failing to load or otherwise throwing an error, it would likely cause execution to stop.  If there are no errors, check the version numbers of all of your AngularJS files (angular, animate, route, cookies) and make sure that they are **all the same version** and at least 1.3.x.  If they are all good, comment out your CSS file and make sure there's not a css conflict (such as using display: block !important).

Comment: @jme11 Thank you for saying check my css! That was the issue... I had a jquery function that would display on click and hidden otherwise. The css was still there and was hidden.

Comment: @jme11 Also, thank you for the advice on just using ui-bootstrap-tpls... I had no idea, I thought you needed both for templates and directives.

Comment: You're welcome.  You can post the answer yourself and mark it to close the question.  It may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I was using Jquery before to toggle the display either hidden or shown.

In my Css I had:

```
myContent {
  display: none;
}
```

Once I deleted that. It worked perfectly fine.